# TYPO3 redirect/cookie set for mobile devices?

Tags: redirect, mobile, typo3, user-agent

I'm looking to do a fairly "normal" useragent check with TYPO3, to detect for any mobile devices, and ALSO check to see if a cookie is set to disable the mobile redirect. In other words, sudo code would be as follows:

```
if(is a mobile device) && (cookie isn't set for disable mobile)
{
   redirect user to domain.com/mobile
}
```

This is all I'd like to be able to do! Can anybody give me any tips? I know you're able to use typoscript to check for a particular user-agent using [useragent = ...], which might work for the user-agent detection, but I'm not sure about the redirect OR checking for a cookie!

Thank you!

Comment: Just wanted to make sure I follow up with this - I ended up finding the best solution was to simply upgrade to a current version of TYPO3 and installing the mobile redirection extension. It was quick, easy, and probably a better implementation then I could have done in a small amount of time from scratch.

Edit: FYI, the extension I used was Mobile Direct,  cwmobileredirect

Answer (score 0):

the [browser=] condition in TypoScript is not very detailed yet might be enough:

- http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.4.0/view/1/4/#id2315154

If thats not enough, consider writing your own condition using [userFunc=functionName(foo)]. That has always proven to be one of the quickest ways in such situations.

I'm not aware of a redirect tag in TypoScript, again I'd suggest usage of a userFunc in which you use PHP's native header() function. If you chose to walk on this path, consider that USER Objects are not working the same way userFunc Conditions do. The conditions cannot process classes. Its just a file of functions which got to be included in a php file like extTables.php (includeLibs does not work!) while the USER or USER_INT object needs a class which is inculded in TypoScript via IncludeLibs.

More:

- http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.4.0/view/1/7/#id2639787
- http://www.florian-rachor.de/artikel/typo3-condition-mit-user-function (use google translate if German poses a problem)

Oh, it might be easiest to store it all in a USER object. In there you can use all sorts of PHP code. Hope that helps you.

cu
Roman

Answer (score 0):

We use a Javascript based redirection which stores the preferences in sessionStorage (Fallback: cookies): https://github.com/sebarmeli/JS-Redirection-Mobile-Site

Just include the JS in your header Data.

Drawback of this solution is, that the page is rendered fully by TYPO3 and redirected afterwards..